# 13.10 and 12.04 discs say I have no Windows 7 on my hard drive

Tags: ubiquity

I installed windows 7 on my new motherboard on a PC I built, and when I put in a Ubuntu disc it tells me I have no operating systems installed when I do. I didn't encounter this problem on my laptop in the past before. Did I somehow screw up on my part?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you check your hard drive with Gparted, you will notice that it will have a Yellow warning mark in any of your NTFS partitions. The way to fix it is shutting down totally Windows (no hibernation, no suspend, but correct shutdown of the system). If that doesn't get rid of the warning, you should run `chkdsk /f` in cmd (just type `cmd` in the start menu) with Administrative Privileges and restart Windows twice.

In case of Windows 8, apart of the actions above, you should disable Fast Boot and shutdown the system.

Comment: I was able to find a fix. the problem was related to a GPT partition table. Deleting it and running the Ubuntu installer again worked in detecting Windows 7 this time.

Comment: @MichaelScott why not add that as answer then?

Answer (score 1):

You can try remounting your Windows drive in gparted. Although this sounds strange but sometimes it works. 
1. Open gparted and close that installation window.

2. In gparted, unmount every hard disk you see (/dev/sda1, for an example)
3. Mount it back, or the installer will fail to check that hard disk for operating systems.
4. Relaunch the installer, and this time it should successfully recognize your system.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Ubuntu disc is bootable. Try it on another PC. Also you must boot from your Disc by pressing specific key combinations.

if the message "No operating system is found" is shown while you are installing Ubuntu, just ignore this and select "Something else" option for formatting. Then select a partition for Ubuntu and install it. The message is shown because sometimes Ubuntu may fail to recognize the OSs