# How to get Ubuntu 13.10 installer to recognize Windows' existence?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

Saw you posted this question, and comment: [13.10 and 12.04 discs say I have no Windows 7 on my hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360407/13-10-and-12-04-discs-say-i-have-no-windows-7-on-my-hard-drive/360779)

Can't get it to work; similar problem. You wrote: "I was able to find a fix. the problem was related to a GPT partition table. Deleting it and running the Ubuntu installer again worked in detecting Windows 7 this time."

Could you please elaborate, here or in a public answer? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks,   James Cropcho

Answer (score 1):

if you want to install UBUNTU 13.10 try live version and go through installation steps and install your UBUNTU if you have a windows on your machine it will recognize you windows and save its bootloader , I've done the same way on my dekstop and my laptop and it went well . 
I had windows 7 on both machin's